# Is there a way to POST a group of form input fields as an object array?

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, node.js, forms

I am dynamically adding a group of inputs to a HTML form and POSTing this form and would like to have the form data represented as an array of objects

I have this HTML form input group which the user can clone and another duplicate input group is added to the form:

```
<div class="questions entry input-group col-xs-3">
  <input class="form-control" id="clue" name="questions[clue][]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Clue" />
  <input class="form-control" id="answer" name="questions[answer][]" type="text" placeholder="Enter Clue Answer" />
  <input class="form-control" id="hint1" name="questions[hint1][]" type="text" placeholder="Optional: Enter a hint" />
  <input class="form-control" id="hint2" name="questions[hint2][]" type="text" placeholder="Optional: Enter a second hint" />
  <button class="btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
    <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

On POST the form data is being represented as follows:

```
questions: { 
  clue: [ 'clue_a', 'clue_b' ],
  answer: [ 'answer_a', 'answer_b' ],
  hint1: [ 'hint_a1', 'hint_b1' ],
  hint2: [ 'hint_a2', 'hint_b2' ] 
}
```

However, I would like to have something more like the following:

```
questions: [ 
  question: {
    clue:   'clue_a',
    answer: 'answer_a',
    hint1:  'hint_a1',
    hint2:  'hint_a2'
  },
  question: {
    clue:   'clue_b',
    answer: 'answer_b',
    hint1:  'hint_b1',
    hint2:  'hint_b2'
  }
}
```

Comment: `questions[0][clue]`, `questions[1][clue]`, ... could do the trick, you  would need a counter variable then.

Comment: I think you are missing some information. HTML doesn't really care about structure. It posts name+value pairs. How are you getting the current example? Are you actually using jQuery? What type of backend are you posting to?

Comment: please add tag for backend language i.e C#, Python, Php etc

Comment: I'm posting to a node backend with express, here is the code to output on the server:

`router.post('/creategame', (req, res) => {console.log(req.body)}`

Comment: @RolandStarke I'll give this a go but wondering is there any option to not have to keep a counter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort them by question, then you need to put the `[]` in the name in the correct order:

```
name="questions[0][clue]"
```

… and so on.

Comment: Trying with `name="questions[][clue]"` I get the following structure but the clue objects should not be arrays


  `questions:
   [
     { clue: [Array], answer: [Array], hint1: [Array], hint2: [Array] } ] }`

Comment: `questions[0][clue], questions[1][clue]` with a counter variable did the trick